# NativeScript BottomNavigation How to do Round Corners?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview

I'm currently working on a NativeScript Project and want to have a BottomNavigation Bar with round corners. I'm using NativeScript Angular with the @nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation Package.

How can I round the top two corners?

I tried to round the corners using css border-radius. It didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using angular, I would suggest to use the bottom bar as implemented by williamjuan027. https://github.com/williamjuan027/nativescript-ui-components